# Applying a quota to network bandwidth (guarantee minimum throughput)

Tags: networking, cisco, iptables, bandwidth, traffic-shaping

I have a 10Mb internet connection (via an ethernet cable)
I have five servers that will use this internet connection.
I want each server to be able to use as much bandwidth as possible when it is not in use by other servers, but guarantee that each server will always have at least 2MB available

What sort of device/configuration is able to handle this setup?  Can it be done somehow with IPTables, or a Cisco ASA etc?

(This is planning for a new setup, so there is no prior commitment to use existing routers/equipment that needs to be taken into account)

Comment: See: [traffic-shaping](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/traffic-shaping), [traffic-management](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/traffic-management), [htb](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/htb) for the Linux solution to shaping.

Comment: Pity these aren't VM's - VMWare's ESXi could do this for you very easily without any hardware. We use Cisco ACEs in Cat65's for this btw.

Comment: Thanks Zoredache - knowing the proper search term is a huge help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Cisco router, you can do it using policy-maps, First, define a service-class for each server (you'll need an extended ACL, so you can match on source IPs), then define a policy-map that allocates a minimum guarantee of 2 Mbps to each service-class.

After that, apply this as an outbound policy-map on your WAN interface (will require that you change the percentage allocatable from 75% to 100%).

```
class-map server1
 match access-group 101
policy-map fair-allocation
 class server1
  bandwidth 2000
access-list 101 permit ip host 10.34.56.78 any
```

You would need to define a class-map for each server and within the policy-map, you'll need to repeat the "class-map server ..." for each server.

Then, on your WAN interface, you'd need to do:

```
interface WAN
 max-reserved-bandwidth 100
 service-policy output fair-allocation
```